# Converting DateTime object to UNIX timestamp retaining milliseconds

Tags: php, datetime

I have a time represented like so `2019-07-01T13:40:50.559Z` and I need to convert it to a UNIX timestamp while retaining milliseconds.

To convert first, I do this:

```
$t1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z', '2019-07-01T13:40:50.559Z', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
```

Printing out

```
$t1: object(DateTime)#24 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2019-07-01 13:40:50.559000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" }
```

It keeps the milliseconds. But if I do `$t1->getTimestamp()` that only returns the seconds `int(1561988450)`. I've searched online and there was talk about `microtime` but I could only see that return the current time. Some people talked about multiplying it by 1000, but that just seems to add zeros.

Can you offer me some guidance to the right path? Thanks.

Comment: Unix timestamps are only precise to the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the microseconds from the `DateTime` and add it to the Unix timestamp as a fraction.

```
$micro = $t1->format("u");
$timestamp = $t1->getTimestamp() + $micro/1e6;
```

Comment: That works great, thank you. I saw your comment up top, I guess technically correct to instead ask how to convert it to milliseconds.